# Why can I access all files in the remote user's home directory over SMB?

Tags: high-sierra, smb

I have two OSX computers and I've been sharing a single folder between the two computers using SMB. The computer hosting the folder was previously running OSX 10.10.1 and I was able to connect from High Sierra by selecting Go -> Connect to Server and then typing `smb://example.net/shared_folder`. After upgrading *both* machines to 10.13.3, trying the exact same operation I get the following error:

[image: There was a problem connecting to the server]

Now, I noticed that I *could* connect to the remote server if instead I tried to connect just to `smb://example.net` directly without specifying the name of the shared folder.

My first question is, why has this behavior changed? This may or may not also be related to this question: [SMB connections throws authentication error after upgrading Mac OS X to 10.13](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300400/smb-connections-throws-authentication-error-after-upgrading-mac-os-x-to-10-13).

However, another interesting thing is that after connecting via the second method which works, I have access to the entire home directory on the remote machine! I have verified that only the default Public folder and the `shared_folder` are set up to be shared on the remote machine. So why when I connect via `smb://example.net` do I get access to the entire home directory?

Comment: When you say "I have access to the entire home directory on the remote machine", are you using that users login or do you have access to *everyone's* home directory?

Comment: Just that user's home directory. I do not have access to all the user's home directories. @Allan, I noticed in the linked question you suggested disabling client signing on the server. Is that a potential solution for the first problem?

Comment: My theory was that there was a shortcoming in Apple's implementation of SMB.  Since the OP of that question didn't respond, I was unable to go any further.